# Secure gcc and g++ options to run programs on a web server

Tags: c++, c, security, gcc, compilation

Okay I know it's usually a bad idea to run user submitted C/C++ code on a web server. But I am trying to make a simple online judge (kind of like [UVa OJ](http://uva.onlinejudge.org)) and I need to compile and run user submitted codes for this. [This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24444/) question has a lot of options listed, but are they enough/excess for a server?

Any other idea is also appreciated.

Comment: you will also need to disable certain libraries. I remember sending a code to my college course that scans for all the files in the current directory, and sends it to me via sockets. I got all the input test cases and the files that all students submitted :)

Comment: No; that question is about preventing *your program's bugs* from allowing exploits, but won't help with things someone writes intentionally (like `system("rm -rf /*")`)

Comment: Worry less about the compiler and more about the runtime environment.  You need to lock down everything the program can do - what files it can reach (chroot), what network it can talk to (varies) and how much resource it can occupy (setrlimit).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. Thanks for your advice. Can you kindly give me a/some link(s) where I can find the proper security measures to take in order to make this secure (like disabling libraries, runtime environment settings etc)?